# How to add events to Google calendar from iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, events, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I know to `add and delete events` in `iCal` from iPhone app programmatically. But, i need to show all other synced calendars from iPhone to the user in my app. And i want to add the user's events to `Google Calendar` or other synced calendars(Like `Yahoo calendar`) instead of iCal. I tried my level best to find the solution in Google. But i can't find any great solutions for my question. I hope on Stackoverflow. Can you please suggest any tutorial, sample code or idea on question. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. I have solved my problem i asked above. I studied something more on `EKEventStore`, `EKEvent` and `EKCalendar` topics, so i did it simple. First i retrieved all calendars from my device(iPod Touch). Then stored all calendars in NSArray by using this code,

```
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[[EKEventStore alloc] init] autorelease]; 
    caleandarsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    caleandarsArray = [[eventStore calendars] retain];
```

Then add the Events to selected calendar by this code,

```
EKCalendar *calendar = [caleandarsArray objectAtIndex:1];
[events setCalendar:calendar];
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:events span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

By using the above code we can add the event to desire calendar. Thanks.

Comment: how you got google calendar in this? [caleandarsArray objectAtIndex:1] gives google calendar?

Comment: I tried to print calendar from array I got first calendar of type local and other of type birthday. How to get google calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Mr.Aldee Mativo. Thanks. I didn't used the Google API in my project. So, i don't know how to use the Google Calendar API. I got the guide to use Google calendar API in iPhone. Please read this.

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html

I don't know whether it is useful for you. Don't mistake me. Thanks.